# Starting Intent from class

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins

I am trying to modify this Cordova plugin example, so I am able to open the native Facebook app from within my app.

I can call the execute() from my webview. But how do I call getOpenFacebookIntent()?

```
/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin
{
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
    {
        if(action.equals("echo"))
        {
            String message = args.getString(0);
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        else if(action.equals("facebook"))
        {
            //call getOpenFacebookIntent here
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            callbackContext.success(message);
        }
        else
        {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/20531316728"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/20531316728"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a context from your application to pass to the intent. You can use `cordova.getActivity()` to get a reference to your context, like this:

```
Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

How I figured this out: I checked the source of [CordovaPlugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java). There, I saw that `cordova` is a public interface, and the following comment in the source showed the way:

> To run on the UI thread, use:
>
> cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);

Comment: Wow thanks! So I just add this line instead of the facebook comment line:

 Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
 
 getOpenFacebookIntent(context);

? Because I tried that, and nothing happens in the app..

Comment: You still have to use the intent somehow, not just return it. For example, `startActivity(intent)`.